# How to Update db field value in hook_menu()?

Tags: nodes, database, hooks

I'm using Drupal 7, my requirement is to automatically update the node field value in a content type for a condition. I have used Hook_menu() for to get a link and if i use that link my code will execute(In Cron). Below is my code,

hook_menu():

```
function status_url_menu() {
$items = array();
$items['update_status'] = array(
'title' => 'Status Update',
'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
'page callback' => 'update_status_url',
);

return $items;
}
```

And to fetch db table data i used db_query()(I have few additional codes too but this is my core concept for my condition):

```
  function update_status_url(){
   $results2 = db_query('SELECT * FROM {field_data_field_status_tracker}');
   foreach($results2 AS $result2){
   $entity_id2 = $result2->entity_id;
   $in = 'Inactive';
   if($entity_id2==568){
        if($mydate2<$nowDate){  // Comparing current system date with my field
          db_query("UPDATE {field_data_field_status_tracker} SET field_status_tracker_value = $in WHERE entity_id = $entity_id2");

   }
  }
 }
}
```

I'm getting error in db_query(update.. line

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Inactive' in 'field list'
```

And I also tried like this too:

```
$result2->my_field = $in;
```

No use i can't update my db field value, whether I'm using wrong method to update field value or please help me to rectify my problem.
Thanks in advance... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code like this and it worked.

```
db_query("UPDATE {field_data_field_status_tracker} SET field_status_tracker_value = 'Inactive' WHERE entity_id = $entity_id2");
```

Thanks :)